# Unable to login even after entering correct credentials

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-login

I have created a separate app for user account management which handles registration, login and logout. However, after successful signup, I'm unable to login even after using the correct credentials provided during signup.

Here are the required code for the review:

---

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email is required.')

        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Username is required.')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,`your text`
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   # required
   date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, add_label):
        return True
```

---

forms.py

```py
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from django import forms
from .models import Account


class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Enter your first name'
    }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Enter your last name'
    }))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Enter your email'
    }))
    phone_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': '(xxx)xxx-xxxx'
    }))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Enter password',
    }))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Confirm password',
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'password']

    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        helper = FormHelper()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password does not match!')
```

---

views.py

```py
from django.contrib import messages, auth
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm
from accounts.models import Account


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            username = email.split('@')[0]
            user = Account.objects.create_user(
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password=password
            )
            user.phone_number = phone_number
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Registration successful')
            return redirect('register')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            # messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in.')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid login credentials')
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

---

register.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<!-- ========================= SECTION CONTENT ========================= -->
<section class="section-content padding-y">
    <!-- ============================ COMPONENT REGISTER   ================================= -->
    <div class="card mx-auto" style="max-width:520px; margin-top:40px;">
        <article class="card-body">
            {% include 'includes/alerts.html' %}
            <header class="mb-4"><h4 class="card-title">Sign up</h4></header>
            <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col form-group">
                        <!--<label>First name</label>-->
                        {{ form.first_name | as_crispy_field }}
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                    <div class="col form-group">
                        <!--<label>Last name</label>-->
                        {{ form.last_name | as_crispy_field  }}
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                </div> <!-- form-row end.// -->
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        {{ form.email | as_crispy_field  }}
                        </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            {{ form.phone_number | as_crispy_field  }}
                        </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                    </div> <!-- form-row.// -->
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        {{ form.password | as_crispy_field  }}
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        {{ form.confirm_password | as_crispy_field  }}
                    </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Register</button>
                </div> <!-- form-group// -->
                {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            </form>
        </article><!-- card-body.// -->
    </div> <!-- card .// -->
    <p class="text-center mt-4">Have an account? <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a></p>
    <br><br>
    <!-- ============================ COMPONENT REGISTER  END.// ================================= -->
</section>
<!-- ========================= SECTION CONTENT END// ========================= -->

{% endblock %}
```

---

login.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<!-- ========================= SECTION CONTENT ========================= -->
<section class="section-conten padding-y" style="min-height:84vh">
    <!-- ============================ COMPONENT LOGIN   ================================= -->
    <div class="card mx-auto" style="max-width: 380px; margin-top:100px;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title mb-4">Sign in</h4>
            {% include 'includes/alerts.html' %}
            <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
               <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
                </div> <!-- form-group// -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                </div> <!-- form-group// -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#" class="float-right">Forgot password?</a>
                </div> <!-- form-group form-check .// -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Login</button>
                </div> <!-- form-group// -->
            </form>
        </div> <!-- card-body.// -->
    </div> <!-- card .// -->

    <p class="text-center mt-4">Don't have account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign up</a></p>
    <br><br>
    <!-- ============================ COMPONENT LOGIN  END.// ================================= -->
</section>
<!-- ========================= SECTION CONTENT END// ========================= -->

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `login` method, this line:

```
auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```

should be

```
auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)
```